# How to get user input from element and provide a accurate response?

Tags: java, android, automation, appium, chatbot

I am trying to make a chat bot on my android phone, right now, I want to make it so that if someone says "Hey man", the bot responds with "Sup man!" I want to be able to add more of these cases as well.

I tried using this method here

```
String A = "Hey man";

MobileElement element = (MobileElement) 
driver.findElement(By.id("com.samsung.android.app.memo:id/editText1"));
String text = element.getText();
System.out.println(text);

if (text == A) {

System.out.println("Sup man!");

} else {

System.out.println("No response available");

}
```

But this doesn't work because `text` = `element.getText()` and not "Hey man". Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this correctly?

Comment: `==` is the wrong way to compare Strings - it tests if the two String objects are _the **same** object_, not just that they contain the same text. You want `if (text.equals(A))` (or `.equalsIgnoreCase`)

Comment: hey man thank you, the if `(text.equals(A))` method worked out, but in what situation would i use the `.equalsIgnoreCase`?

Comment: one more question, what if I wanted to make `A` an array?

Comment: Wrote it up in more detail as an Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing your Strings, `text` and `A`, using `==` which is the wrong way to compare Strings — it tests if the two String objects are the same object, not just that they contain the same text.

You want to compare using `if (text.equals(A))` or, if you want to match without regard to case, you'd use `if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(A))`

With `.equals()` you are looking for "Hey man", but if the person types "hey man" those won't match and the bot won't respond just because of the upper- vs. lower-case "Hey" vs. "hey".  If you want to match the phrase no matter how someone types it you would use `.equalsIgnoreCase()`

If you want to have multiple phrases you could use an array, or some kind of [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and you would loop over it to find a match, something like

```
for (final String phrase : phrases) {
    if (phrase.equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
        System.out.println(some_text_for_that_phrase);
    }
}
```

...where I'm using `phrases` instead of `A` because it's more descriptive.

If you want different responses for each possible matched phrase you would probably want your *Collection* to be a [*Map*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) where the map *key* is the phrase you want to match and the map *value* is the response you would give. In that case you would get the user text and just use it directly to get the response from the map without having to loop

```
final String response = phraseMap.get( userText.toLowerCase() );
if (response != null) {
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

You can't compare ignoring case with map keys, so you'd want to lowercase every key phrase you put in the map, then lowercase the user input so it matches whats in the map. The response values may, of course, be whatever mix of case you want.

How you fill the map with the key phrases and responses would be another separate question.